# шаблоны с переменными аргументами

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Задача:

- Принять в функцию неопределенное количество элементов с разными типами.
- Засунуть все принятое в stringstream

Вопрос:

- Как раскрыть список аргументов и засунуть в stringstream?

Может, нужно использовать другие инструменты для этой задачи? Подскажите пожалуйста какие(просьба, вариант с `ostream` не предлагать)?

```
  template<typename ... Arguments>
            void tfunc(const Arguments & ... args)
            {
                std::stringstream ss;
                //ss<<args; 
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это легко делается при помощи fold expression:

```
template<typename ... Arguments>
void tfunc(Arguments const & ... args)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    (ss << ... << args);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ft6JINmUMUJSu1Jv)

Comment: А не подскажете - я их что-то пока плохо чувствую - как через них (fold expression) вывести, скажем, с пробелом между ними, или с еще каким-то действием (ну, простоты для - посчитать без применения `sizeof...`)?

Comment: Кстати, не подскажете (я не плохо знаком с данной темой) почему сдесь нет отдельной, так сказать, завершающей функции? Тобишь когда у нас остался только один аргумент...

Comment: VS 2017 не переваривает, пишет 'error C2760: синтаксическая ошибка: ожидался токен "<Нет данных>", а не "<Нет данных>"'

Comment: @Harry Можно определить операцию и распаковывать ее, например вывод с порядковыми номерами `auto Print{[&ss, pp{0}](auto && arg) mutable { ::std::cout << "#" << (pp++) << " " << arg << " "; }}; (Print(args), ...);`:  [online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/38JRkQqDxo5WBoh4).

Comment: @Duracell Убедитесь, что у вас стоит версия 15.8.4, а сборка происходит с флагами `/std:c++17` `/permissive-`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch А тут нет рекурсивного вызова функций. То бишь тут инстанцируется только одна функция с тем количеством аргументов, которое ей передали. А `...` будт разворачиваться в вызов `((ss << arg1) << arg2)`

Comment: @VTT, да, помогло, ваш ответ лучший!

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете воспользоваться временным массивом для распаковки пакета параметров.

```
template<typename ... Args>
std::string foo(Args const & ... args)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    using arr_t = int[sizeof...(args)];//Тип массива для удобства
    arr_t{((ss << args << ' '), 0)...};//Создаем временный массив
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Этот способ хорош для С++14 и более старых версий, где нет fold expressions. Явно лучше рекурсии, которую предлагают в соседнем посте. Кстати, `int[sizeof...(args)]` можно заменить на `int[]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вариант с fold expression уже написали, но может и этот кому пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, например, [так](https://ideone.com/TzNQOW):

```
void tfunc(stringstream&)
{}

template<typename T, typename ... Arguments>
void tfunc(stringstream& s, T t, Arguments ... args)
{
    s << t << " ";
    tfunc(s,args...);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    stringstream s;
    tfunc(s,1,0.5,",,,");
    cout << s.str() << endl;
}
```